# Error with pandoc in R

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

Occasionally, I'm getting this error while running code in order to produce output in pdf. I can not figure out why it is to. The code below works but occasionally getting this kind of error. I have to close and re-open RStudio to fix this issue.

Error:

```
 system(paste("pandoc -V geometry:margin=0.7in -o", Reports, "/report", ".pdf ",    
 "report", ".md" ,sep=""))
  pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
  !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file C:/Users/RM/Desktop/figure
  /unnamed-chunk-4.png): reading image file failed
  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

  Warning message:
  running command 'pandoc -V geometry:margin=0.7in -o C:/Users/RM/Desktop/report.pdf 
  report.md' had status 43
```

EDIT:

The error is hardly reproducible. So I wonder if someone would be able to help simply only from the error message itself.

Comment: You said it was hardly reproducible, so I guess it will be hard to diagnose as well. Just a blind shot in the dark: avoid absolute paths wherever possible, and always use relative paths.

Comment: Thanks. Just found out that the memory may be the issue here: Getting this message in about the half of the process. The rest is fine but in one particular plot it gives: Warning in dev.off() : processing of the plot ran out of memory

Comment: reducing the dpi from 600 to 300 solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: You can answer your own question. I wonder why PNG instead of PDF, though. dpi=600 sounds like unusually big, although I rarely use raster images and do not know what the requirement of journals/publishers usually is.